# Difference between set IFS as $'\n' and $' \n'

Tags: bash, shell, ifs

```
#!/bin/bash

show="ls -al /"
IFS=$'\n'
$show
```

The result is like `bash: ls -al /: No such file or directory`.

The shell cannot return expected result.

If I change IFS as `$' \n'` (notice I added a space), it is ok.

I do not have much knowledge about IFS, could someone explain it?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Answer (score 3):

In the first case:

```
show="ls -al /"
IFS=$'\n'
$show
```

The whole string `ls -al /` is being treated as the command name by shell, since IFS doesn't have a space in it and spaces in your variable don't induce word splitting.  It is as good as writing the command as "$show" which completely suppresses word splitting.

In the second case, word splitting does happen since space is a part of IFS.

---

See also:

- [How does IFS work in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493204/how-does-ifs-work-in-bash)
- [Word splitting in Bash with IFS set to a non-whitespace character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163225/word-splitting-in-bash-with-ifs-set-to-a-non-whitespace-character)
- [BashFAQ/050 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: i change IFS to read file each line as below:
`a:1 \n
b:2`
I do not know a good way to read it with bash, do you have a good idea?